# XmlWriter Not Allowing Me to Ignore LocalName When Writing Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, namespaces, xml-namespaces, xmlwriter

How would I create this string using the XMlWriter class? I keep getting an error.

Here is the XML string I am trying to create:

`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="300" height="200">`

Here is the code I am trying to generate it with:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Temp\my.xml")) 
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("svg");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("`xmlns`", null, "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg");
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you don't need to write your own attribute prefix mapping for element's namespace. In this case it looks like properly specifying namespace for "svg" element is what you are after:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(@"C:\Temp\my.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement(null, "svg","http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" );
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Note that code in the post is writing "svg" with empty/default namespace, which is different from having *empty namespace prefix*.

Comment: No way!!!! That is amazing it worked! Thank you so much!!!!!!!